# Data not being passed to variable in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this following code

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    print(data)
    row_count = row_count = sum(1 for lines in data)
    print(row_count)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

It prints:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x00000295CB6933C8>
505
```

So it prints `data` as an object and prints the `row_count` as 505. Just does not seem to print `row` in the for-loop. I am not sure why there is nothing being passed to the variable row?

This is particularly frustrating because if i get rid of `row_count` it works! Why?
[image]

Comment: I don't know how `reader` is implemented, but it's quite likely that after you've iterated through it, counting the rows, it is used up and there's no more to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
print(data)
row_count = row_count = sum(1 for lines in data)
```

You just read the entire file; you've exhausted the input.  There is nothing left for your second `for` to find.  You have to reset the reader.  The most obvious way is to close the file and reopen.  Less obvious ... and less flexible ... is to reset the file pointer to the beginning, with

```
csvfile.seek(0)
```

This doesn't work for all file subtypes, but does work for CSV.

Even better, simply count the lines as you print them:

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

```
row_count = 0
for row in data:
    print(row)
    row_count += 1

print(row_count)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can count the rows while you print them out in the same for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You consumed the rows from data already with your set comprehension:

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    print(data)
    row_count = row_count = sum(1 for lines in data) # This consumes all of the rows
    print(row_count)
    for row in data: # no more rows at this point.
        print(row) # doesn't run because there are no more rows left
```

You'll have to save all of the rows in memory or create a second CSV reader object if you want to print the count before printing each row.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the best solution for you to make that data into a list and itterate through it to save yourself all the troubles if you have some memory to spend

```
with open('your_csv.csv','r') as f_:
   reader=csv.reader(f_)
   new_list=list(reader)
for row in new_list:
   print(row) #or whatever else you want to do afterwards
```